# DataTable.Select filter

Tags: sql, vb.net

I need filter for multiple values on one column using the DataTable.Select method.

```
Dim totalFatal As Integer = _
     m_DataSet.Tables("tblAccidentNonMotorist").Select(String.Format( _
     "[AccidentNumber] = '{0}' AND _
     CONTAINS([InjuryClass], '"01" OR "02" OR "03"'", accidentNumber)).Length
```

Could I use CONTAINS to filter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want 
`"[AccidentNumber] = '{0}' AND [InjuryClass] in( '01' , '02' , '03')"`